# For integer $a$, $m$, $n$ with $a>1$, if $ a^{m} \geq \sum_{i=1}^{a}i^{n} > a^{m-1}$, can we prove $m=n+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a,m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a>1$.

If $$ a^{m} \geq \sum_{i=1}^{a}i^{n} > a^{m-1}$$

Then $m=n+1$.

Comment: Note the middle quantity can be calculated analytically, with it being a fraction of $a^{n+1}$. An MSE question which asks about this, and has more information (including a link to Wolfram MathWorld's [Power Sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html)), is [Sum of powers of natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524587/sum-of-powers-of-natural-numbers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, $\sum_{i=1}^a i^n > a^n$.

We also have $\sum_{i=1}^a i^n < \sum_{i=1}^a a^{n} = a^{n+1}$.

Thus, $a^{n+1}>\sum_{i=1}^a i^n>a^n$.

Answer (score 0):

If $m \leq n$ then the first equality is trivially false (the last term of the sum would be greater or equal to $a^m$

If $m \geq n+2$, then it's the second one that will break, but I couldn't prove it yet. Any help?