# closed-form solution for summed squared error of $n\times n$-grid points to center of gravity

Tags: geometry, summation, closed-form

The context of my problem is the construction of test problems for the $k$-means algorithm and variants of it. The problems should have known optima and are thus constructed from a basic building block which is a regular  $n\times n$ grid of data points filling the unit square.
For $n=2$ the point set would be {(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)} for $n=3$ the point set would be {(0,0),(0,0.5),(0,1),(0.5,0),(0.5,0.5),(0.5,1),(1,0),(1,0.5),(1,1)} and so on.

I like to know the sum of squared distances of all grid points for a given $n$ to the center of gravity which is the point (0.5,0.5).

The naive formula is the following:

$$\mbox{SSE}(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (0.5-\frac{i}{n-1})^2+(0.5-\frac{j}{n-1})^2$$
E.g. $$\mbox{SSE}(2)=2$$

Does a closed-form solution for $\mbox{SSE}(n)$ exist (and how does it look)?

Addendum: Following the remark of @Ian I think one can rewrite the sum as
$$\mbox{SSE}(n)=2n \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (0.5-\frac{i}{n-1})^2$$

which is basically a sum of powers of 2 as described in [Sum of powers of natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524587/sum-of-powers-of-natural-numbers). I should be able to figure out the final formula from here.

Addendum 2: And here is the formula:
$$\mbox{SSE}(n)=\frac{n^3+n^2}{6(n-1)}$$

Comment: It suffices to compute $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i^c$ for $c=0,1,2$, which has been asked before here (I've answered it but I don't recall the name of the answer). The details of that derivation for $c>1$ are a little bit complicated, especially if you do a derivation rather than "select a badly justified ansatz and then find the coefficients".

Comment: Does this answer your question [factor out the constants and collect terms]? [Sum of powers of natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524587/sum-of-powers-of-natural-numbers)

Comment: thanks for commenting! Given your impressive 2730 answers however, this is about as useful to me as Fermat's note "I have discovered a truly remarkable proof of this theorem which this margin is too small to contain" :-). I can't possibly go through all those answers and I am not sure if said answer actually gives me the searched formula (I consider myself not a great mathematician). So, my question is still open.

Comment: I don't understand: who wants to reopen this, given that OP thought the duplicate was acceptable?

Comment: Sorry this was me (OP). I just added the formula I was looking for and which I found through the helpful comments of you and Ian. I thought it might be interesting for someone reading this. Thanks again and the question can remain closed.